# nginx - ungraceful worker termination after timeout

Tags: nginx, websocket

I plan to use nginx for proxying websockets. When performing nginx reload / HUP , I understand that nginx waits for the old worker processes to stop processing all requests. In websocket connection however, this may not happen for long time as the connection is persistent. Is there an option / roadmap to forceibly kill old worker process after timeout on reload?

References:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?21,247573,247651#msg-247651

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have either solution: proxy_read_timeout 1d or a ping message to keep connection alive, Nginx closes connections in 60sec otherwise. This default value was chosen by a reason.

See what Nginx core developer [says](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4411119):

> There is proxy_read_timeout (http://nginx.org/r/proxy_read_timeout)
>   which as well applies to WebSocket connections.  You have to bump it
>   if your backend do not send anything for a long time. Alternatively,
>   you may configure your backend to send websocket ping frames
>   periodically to reset the timeout (and check if the connection is
>   still alive).

Having said that nothing should stop you from using USR2+QUIT signals combination that usually used when you **gracefully** restart Nginx while binary upgrade. Nginx master/worker processes rare consume more than 50MB of memory, so to keep multiple masters isn't that expensive. USR2 helps to fork new master and spawn its workers followed by gracefully shutdown old workers and master.

Comment: If indeed there is a periodic ping from the back-end servers, the connection will not be terminated. However reading again the "Controlling nginx" document after your answer, I thought that after sending HUP to the master nginx, and waiting lets few minutes, I can simply send TERM (fast shutdown) to the old workers still alive, to terminate them.

Comment: yes exactly, USR2 signal forks the new master that starts serving new clients, then QUIT to old master needs to be done originally followed by INT or TERM signal if graceful shutdown doesn't work due to open connections.

Comment: why do you suggest USR2 and not HUP, which will fork new workers without spawning a new master?

Comment: @dux2 USR2 helps to keep new master and its workers separate from old ones. And also to terminate all old workers in one go by sending TERM signal to old master.